# Database gets updated with first entry only in liferay

Tags: liferay-6, jsp-tags

I amusing liferay.
I display some data in a jsp which comes from different tables from database.
I have a radio button field which the user needs to click and then the update should happen when the user submits the form. The problem I am having is everytime only the first value gets updated. Ex. I am having some 5 entries displayed, i click on radio button for each entry and then submit the form. only the first entry is updated. other values are not taken.
what could possibly  be the problem?

here is my jsp:
" method="post" >

```
    <portlet:renderURL  var="viewEmployeeDataURL"/>
```

"
           results="<%= ListUtil.subList(EmployeeAttendanceDetails , searchContainer.getStart(), searchContainer.getEnd()) %>" />

```
        <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text name='Employee Name' value='<%=String.valueOf(search.getEmpFname()) + "  " + String.valueOf(search.getEmpLname())%>'  href="" />


       <liferay-ui:search-container-column-jsp  name = "Attendance Status" path="/admin/radioButtonDisplay.jsp" align="center"/>


       <!-- Get Attendance Remarks for each employee -->

        <liferay-ui:search-container-column-jsp  name = "Attendance Remarks" path="/admin/AttendanceDetails.jsp" align="center"/>

       <!-- Get Attendance Remarks for each employee -->


    </liferay-ui:search-container-row>
    <liferay-ui:search-iterator searchContainer="<%=searchContainer %>" paginate="<%=true %>" />
</liferay-ui:search-container>


<input type = "submit" value = "Update"/>
</aui:form>
```

In the above jsp AttendanceDetails.jsp only displays "remarks" column from database and radioButtonDidplay.jsp is as follows:

    
    " method="post" >
    Present
    Absent

```
</aui:form>
```

When i submit the form,it goes to action class
What is the code for iterating over each entry to update it for each entry?

Comment: I dont think this is a database related issue. looks like you can't set the actionUrl properly. If this is the case, the title you've chosen is misleading. Please update this issue, providing the action-url creation and it's firing control/link, and the Controller's action function. Also your code is not well formatted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer for my question.Obviosuly it wasnt a problem related to the database.
The problem was that I wasn't iterating over the values.
I was getting values from database and was marking attendance for each employee.
The reason for the update of only one entry was due to the fact that


was taking value for only one element.

I used a loop in my action class to iterate over all the values and now it works fine!!